# Is it normal for pandas to need 30 secs to perform calculations on a 50k-row dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I use the pandas read_excel function to work with data. I have two excel files with 70k rows and 3 columns (the first column is date), and it only takes 4-5 seconds to combine, align the data, delete any rows with incomplete data and return a new dataframe (df) with 50k rows and 4 columns, where date is the index.

Then, i use the below code to perform some calculations and add another 2 columns in my df:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    df["new_column1"] = df["column1"] - 2 * df["column4"]
    df["new_column2"]= df["column1"] - 2.5 * df["column4"]
```

It takes approx 30 seconds for the above code to be executed, even though the calculations are simple. Is this normal, or is there a way to speed up the execution? (i am on win 10, 16GB Ram and i7-8565U processor)

I am not particularly interested in increasing the columns in my database - getting the two new columns on a list would suffice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the code in your loop contains neither *row* nor *i*.

So drop *for ...* row and execute just:

```
df["new_column1"] = df["column1"] - 2 * df["column4"]
df["new_column2"]= df["column1"] - 2.5 * df["column4"]
```

It is enough to execute the above code only **once**, not in a loop.

Your code unnecessarily performs the above operations multiple times
(actually as many times as how many rows has your DataFrame) and this
is why it takes so long.

## Edit following question as of 18:59Z

To perform **vectorized** operations like "check one column and do something
to another column", use the following schema, base on boolean indexing.

Assume that the source *df* contains:

```
   column1  column4
0        1       11
1        2       12
2        3       13
3        4       14
4        5       15
5        6       16
6        7       17
7        8       18
```

Then if you want to:

- select rows with even value in *column1*,
- and add some value (e.g. *200*) to *column4*,

run:

```
df.loc[df.column1 % 2 == 0, 'column4'] += 200
```

In this example:

- `df.column1 % 2 == 0` - provides boolean indexing over rows,
- `column4` - selects particular column,
- `+= 200` - performs the actual operation.

The result is:

```
   column1  column4
0        1       11
1        2      212
2        3       13
3        4      214
4        5       15
5        6      216
6        7       17
7        8      218
```

But there ase more complex cases, when the condition involves calling of
some custom code or you want to update **several** columns.
In such cases you should use either *iterrow* of *apply*, but these
operations are executed much slower.

Comment: Many thanks and is it generally advisable to loop through a list or a df? (in terms of speed)

Comment: In this example no explicit iteration is needed. Iteration may be useful in more complex cases, when you are forced to execute a function, e.g. on each row. It can be done also using *apply*, but remember that this is considerably slower that the above vectorized operation.

Comment: i will need to loop through the values of new_column1 and new_column2, so for example whenever new_column1 is greater than a certain value, i will do something with new_column2. So i would like to know what is the fastet way to go through every single value of new columns. Thanks.